# Setting max-height to calc using JavaScript not working (cannot assign to CSS property)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**UPDATE:** Even `document.getElementById("chatbox").style.maxHeight = "calc(100% - 54px);";` with JS didn't work, so the problem is with assigning to the CSS property. Changing the value manually in the Elements tab of the Chrome developer tools works as it should.

There is an event where I create a *p* and insert it before a *div*. I need to then recalculate the maximum height of that *div* to make sure no unneeded scrollbars appear. To recalculate the maximum height I make a string in JS:

```
var mhstr = "calc(100% - 25px - "+pin.getBoundingClientRect().height.toString()+"px);"
```

, *pin* being the newly created *p* element.

The string returns as supposed to: `calc(100% - 25px - 29px);`, however, the `document.getElementById("chatbox").style["max-height"]` doesn't accept it and stays unmodified.

The default original value of max-height is `calc(100% - 25px);`, 25px being the fixed height of an other div that has fixed position.

I tried to add 25 to the pin.getBoundingClientRect().height, but it still didn't work.

Changing the max-height value to the **mhstr** string in the Chrome developer tools does the job, but I want it to be changed via script.

Here is the div object:

```
<div id="chatbox" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: calc(100% - 25px);">
```

Here is the code I use to try and change the max-height value:

```
var mhstr = "calc(100% - 25px - "+pin.getBoundingClientRect().height.toString()+"px);"
console.log(mhstr);
document.getElementById("chatbox").style["max-height"] = mhstr;
```

Note: **mhstr** returns `calc(100% - 25px - 29px);`, changing ["max-height"] or maxHeight to a fixed value like 0, "2px" or "100%" works fine, but doesn't change to the mhstr.

Comment: I think you meant ``document.getElementById("chatbox").style.maxHeight``.

Comment: does the parent element have a fixed `height`? if not, `max-height` included `100%` will not work, inside `calc` or by itself

Comment: I tried both style["max-height"] and style.maxHeight. No difference.
The *div* potentially fills up with other elements, so a fixed height isn't very good for it. The default calc(100% - 25px) works fine, it's just that the style itself doesn't want to change.

Comment: [mre] or it didn’t happen …

Comment: How about `var mhstr = "calc(100% - "+( 25 +pin.getBoundingClientRect().height.toString()+"px);"`?

Comment: If the parent *not have a fixed height* `calc(100% - 25px)` *should not* work.. so it's sound very strange

Comment: `document.getElementById("chatbox").maxHeight` has to be `document.getElementById("chatbox").style.maxHeight`.

Comment: "so a fixed height isn't very good for it."
Then you CANNOT use percentages in your calc. Can you build a calc based on vh instead?

Comment: @RogerKrueger I remember reading that vh weren't supported in some cases so I refrained from using them. Changing the value manually in the Elements tab of the Chrome developer tools works as it should. The problem, I guess, is with assigning the css property.

Answer (score 0):

If  `25px` is a fixed value, why not change your formula like so?

```js
const mhstr = `calc(100% - ${25 + pin.getBoundingClientRect().height}px);`;
document.getElementById('chatbox').style.maxHeight = mhstr;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, max-height still stays `calc(100% - 25px);`

Comment: @GreatCorn Did you check that `console.log(pin.getBoundingClientRect().height);` returns a defined value? And try to `console.log(mhstr);` just to be sure the issue is not in the changing of your css property.

Comment: I `console.log(mhstr)` right before assigning to the maxHeight and it returns the supposed string = `calc(100% - 25px - 29px);`, pin.getBoundingClientRect().height returns 29 as expected

Comment: My code can't return `calc(100% - 25px - 29px);`. It should return `calc(100% -  54px);`.

Comment: Very sorry, kept switching between the two. Your code does return `calc(100% - 54px);`, but maxHeight never changes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a **percentage data type** for `max-height` property, like these examples:

```css
max-height: 100%;
max-height: calc(100% - 25%);
max-height: calc(100% - 25px);
...
```

Then you should have a **parent element with fixed height**.

So it doesn't matter you set the 'max-height' in CSS or JS in this type of case!

---

As you can see in the example below, the first group has a fixed-height parent, in contrast, the second group has an unfixed-height parent.

So the first one is semi-hidden after setting the *max-height*, but the second doesn't change at all!

```js
document.getElementById("fixed-height-child").style.maxHeight = "10%";
document.getElementById("unfixed-height-child").style.maxHeight = "10%";
```

```css
#fixed-height{
  height: 75px; /* parent height is specified exactly */
}

#unfixed-height{
  /* height value is not specified */
}

.child{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-height">
  <p id="fixed-height-child" class="child">
    PARENT WITH FIXED HEIGHT
  </p>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div id="unfixed-height">
  <p id="unfixed-height-child" class="child">
    PARENT WITH UNFIXED HEIGHT
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Parent does exist, however, height is not specified nor fixed: `<div id="chat" style="overflow-y: auto;">`. As I've already said, changing the value manually in the Elements tab of the Chrome developer tools works as it should. The problem, I guess, is with assigning the css property.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox this works flawlessly:

```js
const maxHeight = "calc(20px - 10px)";

chatbox.style.maxHeight = maxHeight;
```

```css
#chatbox {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: calc(100px - 25px);">test</div>
```